# Logging properties to Serilog Email Sink

Tags: serilog

Is there a way to configure the Serilog email sink to also include the additional properties in the email body?

I can see the default format is:

```
{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}
```

But I am not sure if there is an additional token which can be used or a way in code to easily override this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** including `{Properties:j}` in the output template will now include all of the additional properties.

---

To include specific additional properties you can pass `outputTemplate` to the configuration method:

```
.WriteTo.Email(..., outputTemplate: "Machine: {MachineName}")
```

There isn't any "wildcard" to output *all* properties.

Comment: Thanks - the thing is I will not know the names ahead of time. Looking into the source code it looks like I would need to set an alternative ITextFormatter to the default MessageTemplateTextFormatter but as the EmailSink type is not public I cannot do this without editing and rebuilding the Email Sink itself.

Comment: I think if the EmailSink type was made public this would be a lot more straight forward.

Comment: Will this work even if the properties don't exist for the specific log, for example, if I'm exception handling inside of a LogContext with a specified property and also outside of the LogContext without the property?

Comment: There is now a "wildcard" by adding {Properties:j} to the output template.  See https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#output-templates for more details.